# List items type conversion

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list :

```
l = ['UIS006538, UIS036621']
```

I want to convert this to

```
l = ['UIS006538', 'UIS036621']
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split the string item using [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> l = ['UIS006538, UIS036621']
>>> l[0].split(', ')
['UIS006538', 'UIS036621']
```

If you have multiple items in the list, use list comprehension:

```
>>> l = ['UIS006538, UIS036621', 'a, b, c']
>>> [x.split(', ') for x in l]
[['UIS006538', 'UIS036621'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

If you want flat list:

```
>>> [x for xs in l for x in xs.split(', ')]
['UIS006538', 'UIS036621', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: @downvoter, How can I improve the answer?